# Alpha index in IOS music?

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, music

We have two iPads, and one MacBook Pro (MBP) with two users.  All four are on the same Apple ID.   The iPads are similar models on the same IOS, 12.1.1 (16C50) but different memory sizes.  One has cell/GPS.  The two MBP users have the **same** iTunes library path (not sharing separate libraries).  The iPads are synced with different playlists and albums, although most of the albums are on both.

When we set the iPads to the album view, **why does one of them have an A-Z quick index down the right edge and the other doesn’t?**

In the settings for Music, there is nothing to explain this.  If there are settings within the Music app, I can’t find anything to open them.

Comment: By 'them' do you mean the iPads, the MBPs or some mix of the two?

Comment: Maybe this has no answer.  I’ll put it on Apple’s bug report, but they’ll ask me to do half of their work gather a humongous log file, and I will be too lazy.  I’m not going to do for free what I retired from.  :-)